# prevent command line from opening on _popen

Tags: c++, windows

I'm opening a process in C++ like so

```
FILE* pipe = _popen(ss.str().c_str(), "r");
```

This create a cmd window which goes to the forefront of the desktop. I want to prevent the cmd window from opening, and if I can't, a way to keep it minimized.

Tried solutions:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

But that only works if you are calling that function in the process that holds the cmd window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using _popen, use CreateProcess and the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag.

Comment: That was going to be my second choice, but I wanted to avoid going through the CreateProcess routine. Thanks for the peer pressure though :)